# Idiom for trying to cover up defects in one's work

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there any idiom for someone trying to hide or to gloss over or to understate the defects in their work as opposed to covering up to make themselves not look bad?

By "covering up" I mean do something superficial or nominal to pacify the person who pointed out the error but do not actually address the problem (admittedly not precise). By "hide" I mean not acknowledge the problem at all or just disregard the problem or pretend as if there is no problem.

Comment: "Papering over the problem" is a metaphor that I've always taken to refer to applying wallpaper over crumbling walls to hide the broken plaster.

Comment: You'll find the answer provided in above comment. Also, you can use the word *whitewash* when talking about covering up something illegal.

Comment: "sweep it under the rug" cuts it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"Sweep under the rug" may have a connotation of entirely hiding defects. Perhaps "sugar-coating" or "glossing over" might have the less strong connotation of understating defects.